# HTML button onclick property does not call the function, behaving strangely when changed

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am making an app that procedurally generates HTML code from MySQLi database results. It uses a button that calls a JavaScript function that sends an XMLHttpRequest to the server that deletes the row to remove items from the list once they have been processed.
Here is the relevant PHP code:

```php
<?php
require_once("lib/dbclass.php");

$conn = new Conn();
$result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM orders");
?>

<?php foreach($result as $item) {?>
    <div class="row" id="item<?php echo $item['oid']; ?>">
        <p>Type</p>
        <span class="item"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($item['a']); ?></span>
        <p>Size</p>
        <span class="item"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($item['b']); ?></span><br>
        <button type="button" onclick="close('<?php echo $item['c']; ?>')">Item processed</button>
    </div>
<?php }?>
<script src="js/dashboard.js"></script>
```

And here is dashboard.js:

```js
function close(order_id) {
    console.log("Closing order number " + order_id);
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.onreadystatechange = function() {
        console.log("Readystate changed! New: " + this.readyState);
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            console.log("Operation completed.");
            document.getElementById("order" + order_id).remove();
        }
    }
    http.open("GET", "order_complete.php?oid=" + order_id, true);
    http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    http.send();
}
```

However, the problem is that onclick does not call the close function. In the inspect element panel, it shows up correctly as `<button type="button" onclick="close(2)")>Item processed</button>`. but, when I click the button, nothing happens. I have tried:

- Explicitly declaring the button as a button using `type="button"`. Made no difference.
- Removing the parameter from the `onclick` tag so it looked like `onclick="close(1)"`. Made no difference.
- Removing all styling from the button. Made no difference.
- Calling the function from the console. It worked there, and removed the item from the page. So it seems the button is the problem.
- Changing the `onclick` of the button from the inspect panel to `alert("Hi")`. The function called when the button was pressed. When I changed it back to `close(2)` it called `alert("Hi")` again.

Comment: Change the name of your function to something else. AKA `function closeOrder (order_id)`

Comment: @epascarello it worked, is that like a reserved keyword or something?

Comment: [`window.close()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/close)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved: Aparrantly `close()` is a reserved function.
Changing it to `closeOrder()` fixed the issue.